# jsTree nodes click event

Tags: jquery, jstree

I want to redirect to some mypage.aspx page whenever any of the jsTree node is clicked (the ID associated with jsTree node would be passed to that page and page will render accordingly). I've following code in jsTree.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $("#mydiv").jstree({
             "plugins": ["themes", "json_data"],
             "json_data": {
                 "ajax": {
                     "async": false,
                     // the URL to fetch the data
                     "url": "../Handlers/HandleRequest.aspx",
                     "data": function (n) {
                         return {
                             "PassID": "<% = UserNameCtrlID %>"
                         };
                     }
                 }
             },
             // Configuring the search plugin
             "search": {},
             "types": {},
             "ui": { "initially_select": ["node_4"] },
             "core": { "initially_open": ["node_2", "node_3"] }
         });
     });
    </script>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: correct!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: acutually none of the answers worked for me ... how could I accept !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old question but this is what I did to make it work.

- Bind the JStree

  ```
  "plugins" : [ "types", "themes", "json_data" ,"ui"]
  }).bind("select_node.jstree", function(event, data) {
  ```
- Make ajax call to get data and pass the data required in next page as hidden variable.

  ```
  $.ajax({
          type: "POST",  
          url: "getMyData.do",  
          data: inputParam,  
   contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",  
       success: function(response) {  
      var url = '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/nextPage.do';  
            // rediret to next page  
                window.location.replace(url);  
                  }  
      });
  ```
- In the MVC controller - set the session attribute and read that in redirected jsp.
- In JSP convert hidden field to JSON and you have it  to traverse.